# Fabric js not loading images from SVG

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js in my application.

I am exporting the canvas and any objects on it to SVG. The SVG looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 4.1.0</desc>
<defs>
</defs>
<g transform="matrix(0.89 -0.45 0.45 0.89 126 108)"  >
    <image style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;"  xlink:href="http://localhost:53377/ImageHandler.ashx?CaseID=2&ImageID=88&RotationAngle=30&ImagePath=/Case16/9-1.png" x="-23.5" y="-31.5" width="47" height="63"></image>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(0.89 -0.45 0.45 0.89 262 142)"  >
    <image style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;"  xlink:href="http://localhost:53377/ImageHandler.ashx?CaseID=2&ImageID=88&RotationAngle=30&ImagePath=/Case16/9-1.png" x="-23.5" y="-31.5" width="47" height="63"></image>
</g>
</svg>
```

Then trying to load the SVG as follows:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromString("...SVG...", function (objects, options) {
                var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
                canvasZoomer.add(obj).renderAll();
});
```

The ISSUE is that the images are not loaded, if you notice in my SVG there are coupld of images with their paths as well.

Please note, in my case both the images are originally loaded from custom classes, so not sure if they have any bearing on it.

Any help here will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you attempting to load the SVG from a different place than you exported it (i.e. is the `xlink:href` still valid where you are importing the SVG)?

Comment: No. The href mentioned in xlink is available in the same app. i.e. if you were to put that href in a browser it shows the image in the browser.

Comment: also, i dont see any requests made to that URL when the SVG is applied

Comment: Might be an issue with the lack of TLS.  If I replace the URL with a TLS one (https://picsum.photos/200/300) it works, but a non-TLS one (http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1) throws errors.  Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No I am not getting any errors on the console. Also, should TLS matter if I am doing local host based development?

Comment: I am also facing the same error nothing is loading at my end. Please help me guys.